# Integrating GNU/Linux Debian on a Android device : can't create init file because there is already a folder with the same name

Tags: linux, debian, android

I'm trying to boot Debian on my nexus 10 where I have installed android 4.4+cyanogenmod. This is the tutorial that I'm reading: http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian

I'm freezed where he says :

Our new initramfs transfer init control to /etc/init on the GNU/Linux partition. Use this script below. You also need to copy the busybox to /sbin.

/etc/init of SDcard ext4 filesystem

```
#!/sbin/busybox sh

#
# Debian environment boot init script
#
# Leave all the initialization process to the Android init to handle
#

# Launch delayed init script
/etc/init.stage2 >/android/log/boot.log 2>&1 &

# Transfer control to Android init - never returns
exec /sbin/busybox chroot /android /init
```

I can't create a file called init inside the folder /etc because there is already a folder with the same name (/etc/init) that includes these files :

```
networking.conf ;
network-interface.conf :
network-interface-container.conf ;
network-interface-security.conf ;
startpar-bridge.conf ;
udev.conf ;
udev-fallback-graphics.conf ;
udev-finish.conf ;
udevmonitor.conf ;
udevtrigger.conf ;
```

what can I do ? thanks.

Comment: Excusme I don't understand. Did you read the tutorial ? he says to create a file called init that includes these commands : /etc/init.stage2 >/android/log/boot.log 2>&1 &
exec /sbin/busybox chroot /android /init --> where should I write these commands ? inside which file ?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have  to create a file `init` in `/etc`, `init` must be a directory.

`chroot` needs on directory and not a file as its argument